# MySQL Query. Extracting Sum(total) and Sum(total) with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

My question about My
SQL is,

I have a table where users enter time reporting data called time_report. Each time_report is entered  with a service code, each of which has a different meaning and includes a start, stop, time and total.

Here is a example of data entered in the time_report table.

```
t_id Date User Customer Service Closing System  Part    Start   Stop    Total

53 2011-05-02 13 0   48 4   0   0   09:00   17.15   8.15

54 2011-05-03 13 0   49 4   0   0   09:00   17:00    8

55 2011-05-04 13 0   48 4   0   0   09:00   17.15   8:15

61 2011-05-04 1  0  52  4   0   0   09:00   17.15   8:15

62 2011-05-05 1  0  48  4   0   0   09:00   17.15   8:15
```

I am trying to run a query to extract 3 pieces of information.

```
user ( the user is the foreign key to users.user_id)
sum(total) per user.
sun(total) per user where service < 49 
Utilization Percentage: (This will be calculated by dividing the 2 totals )
```

Service is the foreign key to `servicecodes.s_id`

When I try and run the query  to get the sum(total it work okay but I cannot group the information together

```
mysql> SELECT  Users.full_name,sum(total)

    -> FROM time_report, users
    -> WHERE time_report.User = users.user_id
    -> AND date
    -> BETWEEN '2011-0502'
    -> AND '2011-05-11'
    -> GROUP BY User;
```

```
+-----------------+------------+
| full_name       | sum(total) |
+-----------------+------------+
| Cian Higgins    |         26 |
| Wallace Ward    |         23 |
| jason ward      |         42 |
| Thomas Woods    |         72 |
| Peter Jones     |         49 |
| fintan corrigan |         40 |
| David Jones     |         35 |
| January Jones   |         23 |
| Joe Johnson     |         24 |
+-----------------+------------+
9 rows in set, 1 warning (0.09)
```

When I run the query with the service < 49

```
SELECT  Users.full_name,sum(total) AS Productive

FROM time_report, users
WHERE time_report.User = users.user_id
AND date
BETWEEN '2011-0502'
AND '2011-05-11'
AND Service < 49
GROUP BY User;
+-----------------+------------+
| full_name       | Productive |
+-----------------+------------+
| Cian Higgins    |         14 |
| Wallace Ward    |         23 |
| jason ward      |         33 |
| Thomas Woods    |         53 |
| Peter Jones     |         41 |
| fintan corrigan |         32 |
| David Jones     |         27 |
| January Jones   |         23 |
| Joe Johnson     |         24 |
+-----------------+------------+
9 rows in set, 1 warning (0.03 sec)
```

But If I try and join the reports, I get errors....also if I try and run it as a subquery i get errors

Example:

```
SELECT Users.full_name, sum( total ) 
FROM time_report, users
WHERE time_report.User = users.user_id
AND date
BETWEEN '2011-0502'
AND '2011-05-11'
GROUP BY User
UNION 
SELECT Users.full_name, sum( total ) AS Productive
FROM time_report, users
WHERE time_report.User = users.user_id
AND date
BETWEEN '2011-0502'
AND '2011-05-11'
AND Service <49
GROUP BY User
```

this gives all the results in the one row

```
full_name sum(total) 
Cian Higgins 26 
Wallace Ward 23 
jason ward 42 
Thomas Woods 72
 Peter Jones 49
 fintan corrigan 40 
David Jones 35 
January Jones 23 
Joe Johnson 24 
Cian Higgins 14 
jason ward 33 
Thomas Woods 53
 Peter Jones 41 
fintan corrigan 32 
David Jones 27
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement to refine the sum and have both sums returned with one statement.

```
SELECT  Users.full_name
        ,sum(total)
        ,sum(case when service < 49 then total else 0 end) AS Productive
FROM    time_report
        , users
WHERE   time_report.User = users.user_id
        AND date BETWEEN '2011-0502' AND '2011-05-11'
GROUP BY 
        User
```

Comment: @CHig1, you'r welcome. If this answers your question you should accept this answer by clicking on the checkmark. *http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work*